# what does 찢겼을 거란 말이죠 mean?? what is the original verb form here?

Tags: vocabulary

what does 찢겼을 거란 말이죠 mean?? what is the original verb form here?

Comment: Just think it as a contraction of “찢기었을 것이라는 말이지요?”

Answer (score 2):

The verb 찢다 is to tear; 찢기다 is the corresponding passive form 'to be torn'.

So...

> 찢겼을 거란 말이죠

means something like

> so you're saying it got torn?